# How to only allow one toggle div to be shown at a time

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am wondering how I would make this where you can only select one at a time. Please keep in mind this is for Wordpress. For some reason it was not liking "$". If there is an easier way than what I am doing, please let me know! Any feedback is helpful!

## HTML

```
<div id="top-bar" style="width:100%; background-color: #1f2122 !important; padding: 10px 0;">
    <div style="width: 392px; margin:auto;">
        <div id="locations">
            <div id="pull" style=" margin:auto;display: inline-block; padding: 0 9px;">
                <a href="#" class="pullmeshr">Sherman Campus</a>
            </div>
            <div id="pull" style=" margin:auto;display: inline-block;">
                <a href="#" class="pullmedur">Durant Campus</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: #3a3e3f !important;">
    <div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
        <div id="pullmeinfoshr">
            <div id="closeshr">
                <img href="#" src="http://fusionbible.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/close.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                Sherman Campus Info - Coming Soon
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
        <div id="pullmeinfodur">
            <div id="closedur">
                <img href="#" src="http://fusionbible.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/close.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                Durant Campus Info - Coming Soon
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- script to animate campus selector-->
```

## SCRIPT

```
<script>
    window.onOff = 0;
    jQuery(".pullmeshr").click(function() {
        jQuery(".pullmeshr").animate(500);
        jQuery("#pullmeinfoshr").slideDown(500);
        window.onOff = 1;
    });

    if (window.onOff = 1) {
        jQuery("#closeshr").click(function() {
             jQuery("#pullmeinfoshr").slideUp(500);
        window.onOff = 0;
    });
  }
        
    jQuery(".pullmedur").click(function() {
        jQuery(".pullmedur").animate(500);
            jQuery("#pullmeinfodur").slideDown(500);
        window.onOff = 1;
    });

    if (window.onOff = 1) {
        jQuery("#closedur").click(function() {
            jQuery("#pullmeinfodur").slideUp(500);
        window.onOff = 0;
    });
}
</script>
<!-- end campus selector script -->
```

Comment: Read the codex -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to have access to the jquery identifier `$` you can follow the wordpress [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script):

> However, if you really like the short $ instead of jQuery, you can use
>   the following wrapper around your code:
>
> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
>     // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
>     // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
> });
> ```

For the part of the question in the comments, try this (it is a simple solution, it works for 2 choices, but for a list of choices there is a better way than specifying each id/class, using CSS sibling selectors and HTML structure or various other methods)

```
<script>
    window.onOff = 0;
    jQuery(".pullmeshr").click(function() {
        jQuery(".pullmeshr").animate(500);
        jQuery("#pullmeinfoshr").slideDown(500);
        jQuery("#pullmeinfodur").slideUp(500); //add this
        window.onOff = 1;
    });

    if (window.onOff = 1) {
        jQuery("#closeshr").click(function() {
        jQuery("#pullmeinfoshr").slideUp(500);
        window.onOff = 0;
    });
  }

    jQuery(".pullmedur").click(function() {
        jQuery(".pullmedur").animate(500);
        jQuery("#pullmeinfodur").slideDown(500);
        jQuery("#pullmeinfoshr").slideUp(500); //add this
        window.onOff = 1;
    });

    if (window.onOff = 1) {
        jQuery("#closedur").click(function() {
        jQuery("#pullmeinfodur").slideUp(500);
        window.onOff = 0;
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Your response did not answer my main question, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? I will try to help as best I can. You are using id attribute twice, whereas if you wish to select multiple elements you should use the `class` attribute. If you wish to select individual elements you should use unique `id` attributes

Comment: Hey Daniel, basically I am creating a campus selector that when a user selects the campus it will show that campus info. As of right now, you are able to select either one and they will both slide down. I am wanting to fix this where if they first select Sherman Campus (it will slide down) but if they change their mind and select Durant Campus, the sherman campus will automatically slide up without the user having to close it manually.

Comment: Added the code to auto slide up. It's simple and there are better solutions long term (for multiple slide up/downs) but this will function.

Comment: Do you mind posting the code here? I dont seem to see it.